# Protect IP Address and location from Twitter

Tags: privacy, vpn, tor

Is there a way to protect IP Address and location from Twitter after having logged in ? All I want Twitter to know is my email and password and nothing else. No IP Address, no location. Is that possible somehow ? What is the best way to do this ? VPN or Tor or something else that works for this purpose ?

Comment: Twitter will get the IP of your ISP not yours if this is relevant to your question.

Comment: VPN is enough if you are signing up as a new user. First, your browser cookies for twitter should be cleared.

Answer (score 1):

VPN is enough.

You can do it in 2 ways:

- subscribe to a VPN service that may allow you to choose your server from a very wide range of locations
- use browser-integrated VPNs like Opera has or browser modules like browsec (which can be free or payed/premiums that allow more locations/servers to be selected).

Comment: Tor browser is another option, and provides protections against device fingerprinting. Twitter may require a carrier phone number when creating an account through VPN or Tor. Always use the same method to access a particular Twitter account, and use a time-based 2FA, to avoid login challenges. With a VPN, use a common privacy-protecting browser on a common platform, not an app.

Comment: You should also use either the VPN or Tor to initially signup with Twitter. I would also use a "burner email," which doesn't link back to me.

Comment: Tor works too, it's just gonna be most of the time significantly slower.